# React Native Version Upgrading process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to know that whether I need to upgrade react native version alone or I should upgrade node version also.Because there are many other package which need to be in latest version for the project I am working on.So can you guys guide me "The process of upgrading version of existing react native project"

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the guide given in the [react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/upgrading) but to upgrade you should simply need to run

```
npx react-native upgrade
```

and then follow the instructions.

If you have Node 14 or newer you shouldn't need to upgrade Node.

Comment: I am having node 14.16.1

Comment: You won't have to upgrade node then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) of react-native you just need to add your current react native version and your desired react-native version for upgrade  and it will show you what you need to update you don't always need to change all files it shows it will work mostly after updating `package.json` and `pod file`.